# Sails.js response return 'Set-Cookie' header in lowercase

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, sails.js

When i try to set cookie for response from controller, i get header 'set-cookie' in lowercase. Not such browsers can parse that header in lowercase and save his cookie value. Methods below set header 'set-cookie' in lowercase, it save cookie in Intenet Explorer, but not in Chrome. My sails.js version 0.12.3. I want get header 'Set-Cookie' in uppercase for all response. How can i fix this problem?

res.set('Set-Cookie', sails.config.cookieName + '=' + TokenService.newToken(user.id));
    res.cookie(sails.config.cookieName, TokenService.newToken(user.id));
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', sails.config.cookieName + '=' + TokenService.newToken(user.id));

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hT4.png)

I am hope for your help, thanks!

Comment: Unable to understand your problem. `res.cookie('key', 'value')` should work. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes, it work for Internet Explorer, but not for Chrome. Because header looks like this: 'set-cookie', and Chrome can't parse and save him. I need get header from Sails in view like this: 'Set-Cookie' (in uppercase). This problem occur when i deploy new project with Sails version 0.12.3. In my previous project it works successfully.

Comment: Try this: `res.cookie('key', 'value', {secure: true});`

Comment: I try this, but without effect. I get this response http://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hT4.png